# How to resolve the unknow packaging atlassian plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jira

i try to develop a jira plugin , but my pom.xml always has the same problem :

Project build error: Unknown packaging: atlassian-plugin    pom.xml line 19 Maven pom Loading Problem.

THis is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.spectrumgroupe.jira.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>cherifa.jira</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>cherifa.jira</name>
    <description>This is the fr.spectrumgroupe.jira.plugins:cherifa.jira plugin for Atlassian Refapp.</description>

    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging> //the error is always here
```

how can i solve this problem please.

regards

Comment: your packaging type cannot be `atlassian-plugin`. Maven does not recognise this packaging type. What's your output type for this build?? jar/war/zip?

Comment: The pom.xml looks incomplete... Could you paste the full pom.xml ? It looks like you might miss the jira-maven-plugin which is able to recognize the packaging type `atlassian-plugin`. I suggest reading these docs about the Atlassian Plugin SDK: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/working-with-maven/